# Generate Regex to find strings with following condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0, office-interop

Please suggest me regex pattern for the string like below:
<[XYZ-ABC]>

I have to find these strings using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and then save the search string in database.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: For a second I thought you were trying to [parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/643085)

Comment: I am new to using regex expressions, so was confused and posted for help. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got one answer please let me know if its correct:

```
<[^/>]*>
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Regex angleReg = new Regex(@"<([^>]+)>\s+<([^>]+)>");

private string[] parse(string rawInput)
{
    Match angleMatch = angleReg.Match(rawInput);

    if (angleMatch.Success)
    {
        return new string[] { angleMatch.Groups[1].Value, angleMatch.Groups[2].Value };
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In a .NET regex, the things like `[^abcd]` mean "anything not a, b, c or d" so in our case we want anything not ">". `[^>]+` means "anything not >" "one or more times" which is what `+` is. So `a+` matches "a", "aa", "aaa", etc. `(x)(y)` matches "xy" but then, in your Match object, the .Groups list will contain "x" at `Groups[1]` and "y" at `Groups[2]` for easy access to the matched strings.